# Typescript: String literal argument from dynamic array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have the following code for a query building I'm writing for fun:

```
export enum ColFlag {
  PrimaryKey = 1,
  NotNull,
  Unique,
  Binary,
  Unsigned,
  ZF,
  AutoIncrement,
  GeneratedColumn
}

export interface IColumn {
  name: string;
  alias?: string;
  flags?: ColFlag[]
}

export class Column implements IColumn {
  name: string = '';
  alias?: string;
  flags?: ColFlag[] = [];

  constructor(init?: Partial<IColumn>) {
    if (init) {
      if (init.name) this.name = init.name;
      if (init.alias) this.alias = init.alias;
      if (init.flags) this.flags = init.flags;
    }
  }
}

export interface ITable {
  name: string;
  columns: IColumn[];
}

export class Table implements ITable {
  name: string = '';
  columns: Column[] = [];

  constructor(init?: Partial<ITable>) {
    if (init) {
      if (init.name) this.name = init.name;
      if (init.columns) this.columns = init.columns.map(c => new Column(c));
    }
  }
}

export class Query<T extends Table> {
  table: T;
  cols: Column[] = [];

  constructor(table: T) {
    this.table = table;
  }


  select(cols: (T['columns'][number]['name'])[]): this {
    // do stuff
    return this;
  }
}
```

Which when used looks like:

```
const testTable: ITable = {
  name: 'test_table',
  columns: [
    {
      name: 'id',
      flags: [ColFlag.AutoIncrement, ColFlag.NotNull, ColFlag.PrimaryKey]
    },
    {
      name: 'value'
    }
  ]
}

const query = new Query(testTable).select(['value']);
```

My current solution transpiles just fine, but it doesn't provide any meaningful intellisense. Incorrect values will also be accecpted by the transpilers. Is there any to dynamically determine the string values of the objects within the `columns` array to act as string literals and catch build-time errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how in-depth to go here, but the basic issue is that both you and the compiler are widening types to the point where the information you care about (i.e., the string literal values of the `name` field of the `columns` array) is lost.

First, you: by annotating `testTable` as `ITable`, you're telling the compiler to completely forget anything more specific about the actual value assigned.  The compiler will dutifully check that the value is assignable to `ITable`, and then from there on out, the value of `testTable` is known only to be an `ITable`.  Any particular column names have been widened to `string`.  So the easiest thing to do here: don't annotate the type.  Instead, let the compiler infer a narrower type and then pass to it `new Query()` later.  If `testTable` is a bad `ITable`, it will be caught when you call `new Query()`.  So you're not losing any type safety here.

Second, the compiler: generally the compiler sees string-valued properties and assumes that you want to treat them as `string`, not as whatever you've initialized them to.  So if I write `let a = {name: "x"}`, this is inferred as `{name: string}`.  If it were inferred as `{name: "x"}`, many people would be unhappy when `a.name = "y"` fails with a compiler error.  In your case, you never want to change the `name` value, so we need to convince the compiler not to widen it.  There are several ways to do this; a reasonably straightforward one is to use [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const testTable = {
    name: 'test_table',
    columns: [
        {
            name: 'id' as const,
            flags: [ColFlag.AutoIncrement, ColFlag.NotNull, ColFlag.PrimaryKey]
        },
        {
            name: 'value' as const
        }
    ]
}
```

So, you'll see that `testTable` is not annotated, and the `name` fields of the `columns` arrays are `const`-asserted. If we inspect the type of `testTable`, we'll see this:

```
/* const testTable: {
    name: string;
    columns: ({
        name: "id";
        flags: ColFlag[];
    } | {
        name: "value";
        flags?: undefined;
    })[];
} */
```

That is hopefully specific enough to meet your needs.  Let's try it:

```
const query = new Query(testTable).select(["value"]); // okay

const badQuery = new Query(testTable).select(["valve"]); // error!
//  ----------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"id" | "value"'.(2322)
```

Looks good.  You'll find that IntelliSense should prompt you to enter `"id"` or `"value"`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIQDYDFsCGA5nAN4BQcVcAClAJaoFQCeA0sC3ALxwCMAGkrUAchBgjk2bEOpwAqonoBHZMFnUAQvUTMWGqooDO9IomAATA3ABauawEFkMCAElEAYyjBUSGNYBxJGAoAhhLLGw0RHIAX3JyUEhYOB1wqAAzAg9gOFdI6LJhKl1fAC44IxgGRCIAbmK4Amx6AiMAfgqqmvrGjMIiDorI-GIAbQBdOISk6HgPQiMjTBxCxjBsHz9l-NXURCK5UuAu6p0SXgByS4a5ZtahyrPa2+p+4keRgcmeOEmGxoeCCIbrIDwuKAACh09BgnVozBgrWwAB5dlF9gA+ACUhzk1HoGTg0KUMFxFHxlNSRJJsIAdMdcTAABb0IwMgi+X4wmAc3yvKkEmk8un3NpM1nssXLXgi6UCwXU4ki96DCVsumqmWpUmagZGBVyeJG6aJcBzHXpLI5PIAFQIACNNniSpyTk8egqgRiQRV0dF-qbZikFm1lvanbl1ptfIgYDsI86KdRjqcer9rl69r6Vj6frxA4DgaDwdBaXCKjREci0YngDiXfjCcrSeTGoLm+W+cB1ezjtzdcdDVTOyLvdEjL26eP9tqx9n2UwwJCPDxMXBzAB3XPRFfY7HDqjG6jxeJm5LzRbLACKalYKNtCBA4UQFnDjs26+TVBgH-dtqzbAjGGbN8z+CYATkIEQWqMEIUhX9IwqW020FFkNUQ51eEw4AFTPOQjGATZwRXHBgOJW0xkuGcQUuCYxhQVAHRCejLmOOjsUmbEKnQ5Zv3xAB6AS4AsCAnmQDIMnbahvBgZAoAOXi8NNaCqjgcIqjrX5+NTOBLg0mAAH0cMuawaPIsZpKofjBV0y56AsS4mmWVT-Cs-EtQqMYvmIOknBcdwvC2OMBFzUYiDpMQJCkGQwoGOk6EYPQOBYKZBViaw5Bsqk7IAN2aNQnLaOBXPc48qCmM8BIAKhK4t4AMusKh0t003OQCJwqSFstdco4AAIgc-rDzgTy4vGCDGliOAAB9GyOVqBvyqJgGG9ytXhZBX2ADIdEsPDOMm6bqoEhJXLgVQQi4XgtzgW8roQ4BNL-bE6UI4iYEhMZ+uWtR+omA84CEuAIAAawIFgzvquAHQICx7tYX5boRlhHueyNXve4ASO+5bctWgG6iB4SQigaAAEJyGBuAAFo6fphnGaZ5mWYZ9cAD9Oa59mqeE20WDAXJLm6c4nLZDdxGckwzD-dSxJgAWhcGix+tmpaCtWy46UhAAmABmHWdexIA)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was looking for! With removing the `ITable` type annotation from our object, is there any way to preserve intellisense when building that object out?

Comment: You might make a generic helper function like `const asITable = <T extends ITable>(t: T)=>t` and call `const testTable = asITable({...})`;  That should prompt you inside of the argument to `asITable` without widening.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIQDYDFsCGA5nAN4BQcVcAClAJaoFQCeA0sC3ALxwCMAGkrUAchBgjk2bEOpwAqonoBHZMFnUAQvUTMWGqooDO9IomAATA3ABauawEFkMCAElEAYyjBUSGNYBxJGAoAhhLLGw0RHIAX3JyUEhYOB1wqAAzAg9gOFdI6LJhKl1fAC44IxgGRCIAbmK4Amx6AiMAfgqqmvrGjMIiDorI-GIAbQBdOISk6Hg0kKycvIAVAgAjbFyKOVLgLuqdXrkPHGijCvyz1ERJhvjyU8QqpqNXNc3c3gAeFYQQcKICxGVYbLYAPgAFDAKisAJQ8cFwGAJJ4vcJVD5bHivd5g4CQnbUPYVABEpOspyiNwucDGjTkRLkzLgJLgAHJ6BZ2a84Gj-AyWXB+sRaWMRgMAHROFzuLw+PwCTA4UZESViCRSGTKvBSuiMPQcFhTIVwWLWRmClls9kAN2aah5bT5EGeKNN8TkU1icIaQA)

Comment: With a helper function, you can also [avoid](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIQDYDFsCGA5nAN5xwAKUAlqgVAJ4DSwjcAvHAIwA0cAOQgwBybNn4BBZDAgBJRAGMowVEngBfOAHptcRQAsIYAFAnQkWHBqIYwKADMCi4HDlZsaRGRMUKiAjUALjgAZxhaRCIAbl8-AmwaAlCAfhDwyJi4igdCIlSQj3xiAG0AXRMNMwtoeBs7R2dXOQAVAgAjbFdSbLgA4LCImyy-fRwvUJD3cdREctiqk0UIRHC4ZNaOrs44AB4AZQQQO0QAE1DBzN5elqOT87c2ztcAMjIxz1nJ9-7gEMONOU4BoAHwAChgIRaAEpOCC4DAzMtVvA7OEntsuBsMcAwT1Rr8QgAiInXUbLT6rEIlXqjfGjBn+QJ-OAAchop1ZZMZDNyxG+JSKeQAdNJZAplKp1PwhcRhUIRGIJJgcMUiMLqHQGCw2BUecDuYz6fqmQNWQA3BLIYCs2l+KqjCoaaGxIA) the `const` assertion

Comment: Is there any reading material or topics that I could research to learn more about the patterns all described within this post? Thanks for all the help!